# background image not showing vue.js

Tags: html, css, vue.js, background, background-image

I've tried every combination that was given in the answers throughout the different sites.
Here's my code.

`<div class="circular" v-bind:style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + require('../assets/kafa.jpg') + ')' }"></div>`

The problem is (I think) that path is good, and image is found, it just won't show on the background (or anywhere for that matter).

[And here is the image of the page and Inspect Elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2gib.png)

Thanks.

Comment: I see this DIV has height equals 0. Try to set it to something more appropriate.

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work still... Thanks anyway.

Comment: And after that a DIV has a non-zero calculated height in dev tools?

Comment: It stays the same. Literally nothing changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I found the problem. I closed the  tag in the same line, instead of wrapping whole template in that div.

Answer (score 0):

> According to vue documentation:
> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/class-and-style.html
> in the section of “Binding Inline Styles” and “Object Syntax” it describes that you could define peroperty-values of styles in the “data” part of “vue instance”. This is what I was doing for implementing that:

```js
new Vue ({
    el: "#app",
    data: {
        activeColor: "red",
        backImg: 'url("galaxy.jpg")'
    }
});
```

```css
.circular {
    min-height: 1080px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div id="app">

        
    <div class="circular" v-bind:style="{color: activeColor, backgroundImage: backImg}"> texts to show styles</div>
        
    </div>
    
    <script src="vue.js"></script>
    <script src="myScript.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

> I used the “camelCase” format and the image is something different, you can substitute your own “url” in the “data” part of “vue instance” in the script code. I could not upload my used image, but you could test your own image.

Comment: I did this already. Actually everything I did would probably work, but since I closed div right away, it didn't show (I posted my answer). Thanks anyway.